# Three.js Extruding standard complex geometries

Tags: three.js, geometry, shapes, vertices

I created a ring geometry that I used to represent a plane in a sphere. The problem with this geometry is that if I put the camera in perpendicular, it disappears because it has no width.

To solve that I want to extrude this geometry instead of directly creating the mesh.

There is a lot of posts on how to create the shapes needed to extrude by pushing points and holes and whatever, but not on how to obtain this vertices correctly from a geometry.

First I tried to create the shape passing the vertices of the ring geometry directly. It fails with an undefined at "vertices":

```
var orb_plane_shape = new THREE.Shape(ring_geom.vertices.clone());
```

Then, I tried to copy the vertices vector, place by place, and give it to the Shape constructor. It works but with the following problems:

-A warning: unable to triangulate polygon! 
-There is no clear hole in the ring, and looks like the vertice connection order has changed.

```
    var vertices = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < ring_geom.vertices.length ; i++) {
        vertices.push(ring_geom.vertices[i].clone());       
    }
    var orb_plane_shape = new THREE.Shape(vertices);
    // extrude options
    var options = { 
        amount: 1,              // default 100, only used when path is null
        bevelEnabled: false, 
        bevelSegments: 2, 
        steps: 1,                // default 1, try 3 if path defined
        extrudePath: null        // or path
    };

    // geometry
    var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( orb_plane_shape, options );

    plane_orb = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material_plane_orb);
```

I would like to establish a method to convert any of the standar 2D geometries (circle, ring...) to a shape, to be able to extrude it.

Thanks

Comment: The vertices for the shape and the hole have to be in proper counterclockwise order, and they are likely not. You will have to build your extruded ring from an extruded circle and a hole.

Comment: Maybe someone, by looking to the implementation of RingGeometry can give me a clue. I can see the order how they are saved but there are also faces and no holes. If I use phiSegments=1 I will expect to have only one circle of vertex and one circle of holes, but as I said, there are no holes in the function. Looks like it creates many independent polygons to build the partial ring.

Comment: Are you willing to do what I suggested in my first comment?

Comment: You mean that if I create a Circle instead of a ring, the vertices will be sorted, so I can create a solid circle and a hole circle and then use their vertices to build it? That is actually almost giving the vertex manually because it's just aplying sinus and cosinus. It is not what I was intending, but finally if anybody knows a better way, I will have to do it in this way.

Comment: Finally I did it manually, but I will leave this question open in case someone knows how to handle the vertices already created in geometries. I hope soon or later we could simply generate a geometry and extrude it without talking about vertices, one level of abstraction higher. The problem with RingGeometry I think comes because this geometry is built by triangles with faces, not concentric circles, but I am sure there is a way to fix it, just that can be different for each geometry.